# Error in mice.impute.polyreg: dims do not match the length of the object

Tags: r, r-mice

I am using a data frame with 40 columns and 2000 rows. The columns are mostly factors and ordered factors, two are numeric.

I want to impute the missing values using the mice package using the following code:

```
init<-mice(mydata, max=0, print=FALSE)
pred<-init$predictorMatrix
methods<-init$method
imp_data<-mice(mydata, predictorMatrix = predmat, meth=methods, m=10, diagnostics=TRUE)
```

The 
error message I receive is:

```
Error in mice.impute.polyreg(1L,1L,3L,3L,1L,3L,1L,1L,1L,1L,: 
dims [product 6] do not match th lenght of the object [7]
In adition warningm messages:
1: In multinom(formula(xy), data=xy[ry, drop= FALSE], weights=w[ry],: group 
'7' is empty
2: in un > appply (post,1,cumsum):
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I have tried to reproduce this error message with build in data sets, but I couldn't.

Can anyone explain to me the meaning of the error message and might know what I need to change in my data structure or mice formula?

Comment: I would use `options(error=recover)` and investigate exactly which object is giving you the error. You may find your data is not what you thought.

Comment: I tried this before posting the question here, but unfortunately it did't help in this case

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32439/how-do-i-fix-this-error-in-mice-multiple-imputation/510071#510071 for possible solution. Drop levels of unused factors.